# CakePHP pagination like laravel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cakephp, laravel, pagination

In LARAVEL we have a native bootstrap pagination with :

```
<?php echo $posts->links(); ?>
```

result is :

[image: laravel]

In CAKEPHP we can put :

```
<ul class="pagination">
<?php
    echo $this->Paginator->prev('&larr; Previous', array(
        'class' => 'prev',
        'tag' => 'li',
         'escape' => false
    ), '<a onclick="return false;">&larr; Previous</a>', array(
        'class' => 'prev disabled',
        'tag' => 'li',
        'escape' => false
    ));
    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
        'separator' => '',
        'tag' => 'li',
        'currentClass' => 'active',
        'currentTag' => 'a'
    ));
    echo $this->Paginator->next('Next &rarr;', array(
        'class' => 'next',
        'tag' => 'li',
        'escape' => false
    ), '<a onclick="return false;">Next &rarr;</a>', array(
        'class' => 'next disabled',
        'tag' => 'li',
        'escape' => false
    )); ?>
</ul>
```

the result is less beautiful :
[image]

So, how to pimp the cakephp code for produce same result of laravel ?

Comment: What do you mean by "less beautiful" ? The fact that the arrows were replaced by "Previous" and "Next" or the fact that there isn't "..." in the middle of the page numbers to avoid having a very long page selection block ?

Comment: The "..." with links for lasts pages, i didn't see if there is a param for that

Comment: [Looks like](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html#creating-page-number-links) there is an `ellipsis` parameter for `Paginator->numbers`, so I assume that it's automatically used once there's enough pages. You may try to set the `modulus` parameter to something small like 2 and see if that gives you the desired result.

Comment: Thks ! all is good ! :)

Answer (score 2):

Solution is :

```
echo $this->Paginator->numbers(
    array('modulus' => 2,
        'separator' => false,
        'before' => '',
        'ellipsis' => '<li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>',
        'after' => '',
        'tag' => 'li',
        'class' => false,
        'currentClass' => 'active',
        'currentTag' => 'a',
        'first' => 3,
        'last' => 3,
    )
);
```

Thks to André Daniel

Answer (score 2):

The tb way can be:

```
<?php $paginator = $this->Paginator->params(); ?>
<?php if ($paginator['pageCount'] > 1): ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <nav class="text-center">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <?php
                    echo (!$this->Paginator->hasPrev()) ? '' : $this->Paginator->prev('«', array('tag' => 'li'), null, array('tag' => 'li', 'class' => 'disabled', 'disabledTag' => 'a'));
                    echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
                        'separator' => '', 
                        'ellipsis' => '<li class="disabled"><a>...</a></li>',
                        'currentTag' => 'a', 
                        'currentClass' => 'active',
                        'tag' => 'li', 
                        'first' => 1,
                        )
                    );
                    echo (!$this->Paginator->hasNext()) ? '' : $this->Paginator->next('»', array('tag' => 'li', 'currentClass' => 'disabled'), null, array('tag' => 'li', 'class' => 'disabled', 'disabledTag' => 'a'));
                    ?>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```